# How to update libnl in Fedora?

Tags: software-installation

I was able to locale `libnl` (and few of its child) in */usr/lib64*. I'd like to install `libnl3-devel-3.2.29-2.fc25.x86_64.rpm` there BUT my current version of `libnl` is an earlier version (3.2.27..) So I'm having trouble ...`dnf libnl` is not working...

I'm doing all this to install `aircrack-ng`

Could you help me install it (especially `libnl-3-dev` and `libnl-genl-3-dev`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mentioned which distro you have; is it Fedora 24 ? I have Fedora 25. I ran just now `dnf update`, and after it completed (it took about 20 minutes), running `rpm -q libnl3` gives `libnl3-3.2.29-2.fc25.x86_64`, which is what you want.
I need to add that before running `dnf update` I had `libnl3-3.2.28-3.fc25.x86_64` and not 3.2.27 as you.

Regarding `libnl-3-dev` and `libnl-genl-3-dev`: these are Ubuntu/Debian packages, not Fedora/CentOs packages. I installed the parallel `libnl3-devel` Fedora package (again on this F25 machine) by `dnf install libnl3-devel`, and it installed `libnl3-devel-3.2.29-2.fc25.x86_64`. Not sure about `libnl-genl-3-dev`.

Rami Rosen

Comment: I was able do to as you said...but I cant find the equivalent of `libnl-genl-3-dev` anywhere...I m still looking

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in Fedora, there is no such package. If you will look at the contents of the Ubuntu package libnl-genl-3-dev, you will see that in fact it consists merely of 4 files, and the significant among them is: /lib/libnl-genl-3.so

for example here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libnl-genl-3-dev/filelist

However, when you will look at the contents of libnl3-devel rpm of Fedora, you will find out that /lib/libnl-genl-3.so is included in the files which are provided by libnl3-devel:
http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/25/x86_64/l/libnl3-devel-3.2.29-2.fc25.i686.html

The fact that it appears there as /usr/lib/libnl-genl-3.so and not as 
/lib/libnl-genl-3.so is not important.

So it seems that in Fedora, libnl3-devel contains also libnl-genl-3-dev.

Rami Rosen